# AddDataProtection - Register PersistKeysToFileSystem and PersistKeysToDbContext at the same time

Tags: .net-core, encryption, dependency-injection, data-protection, key-management

While using the Data Protection API and I register AddDataProtection with both **PersistKeysToDbContext** and **PersistKeysToDbContext**.
How do I choose which one to use when I call CreateProtector on IDataProtectionProvider in the Controller?
I am hoping I do not have to create multiple solutions just for a one line difference!

Here I register Data Protection

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    //.PersistKeysToDbContext<DataContext>() //Not sure how to choose between both
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(folderPath))
    .SetApplicationName("my-app");
```

Here, at the moment, I can only use one or the other

```
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

    public FileSystemKeyManagementController(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
    {
        _dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("my-app");
    }
```

I am looking for a solution where, for example, FirstController will use `PersistKeysToFileSystem` and SecondController uses `PersistKeysToDbContext`.
So when I call `_dataProtector.Protect("string to secure")` depending on controller, the data either ends up on a file system or database table.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

I tried registering both `PersistKeysToDbContext` and `PersistKeysToFileSystem` but the last seems to win.